# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir el precio de un producto por otro generado mediante JS en Woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy haciendo una tienda online y me encuentro en la siguiente dicha;
Todos los productos de la tienda tienen un precio de 0€.  El precio se calcula dependiendo de una serie de atributos, como la anchura y altura (estas mediante condiciones), el tipo de material etc.
Hasta ahora, lo que tengo es un botón que, una vez pulsado, llama a una función y calcula el precio final del producto, escribiéndolo en el DOM para que el usuario lo visualice y proceda si quiere a comprar el producto.
En el funtions.php de mi tema tengo el siguiente código:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
        $nuevoPrecio = ""; // Precio calculado por JS 
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            $value['data']->set_price($nuevoPrecio);
        }
}
```

He probado el gancho escribiendo yo el valor manualmente y funciona, el problema es que no sé como llevar el precio que calculé en JS a esta parte y hacer que el precio se modifique, he oido que con AJAX, pero no se como hacerlo.
Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda de forma anticipada a todos.

Comment: Hola! Me alegro de que encontraras solución. Ahora te recomiendo esta lectura: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia Un saludo!

Comment: Kotori: en lugar de marcar como "solucionado", publica tu propia respuesta y acéptala → [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

no comprendo en su totalidad tu pregunta, pero si quieres utilizar AJAX te puedo dar un ejemplo de como podrías utilizarlo:

Te recomiendo que trabajes orientado a objetos

Agrega esto en `functions.php`

```
class Prefijo_Calculador_Ajax {

        protected $nuevoPrecio;

        public static function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {


            foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

                // Aquí se utilizar la propiedad $this->nuevoPrecio para pasar el valor
                // obtenido por AJAX
                $value['data']->set_price( $this->nuevoPrecio );

            }

        }

        public static function receptor_ajax() {

            check_ajax_referer( 'nombrenonce', 'nonce' );

            // Recibes el valor por medio del método POST
            // y lo guardar en la propiedad $this->nuevoPrecio para que pueda
            // ser usado por el método add_custom_price()
            $this->nuevoPrecio = $_POST[ 'nuevoPrecio' ];

            // Agregas el gancho llamando al método
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', [ self:class, 'add_custom_price' ] );

            // Puedes devolver algún valor para validar
            /*echo json_encode( [
                "resultado" => ''
            ] );*/

            wp_die();

        }

        // Método que localiza el archivo y crea el objeto de valores a utilizar
        public static function objeto_javascript() {

            wp_localize_script(
                'nombre_del_archivo', // Aquí colocas el nombre que se utilizó en wp_enqueue_script() para encolar tu archivo Javascript y donde vas a trabajar con AJAX
                'nombreobjeto', // Nombre del objeto a crear para utilizarlo en el archivo Javascript
                [
                    'adminUrl'      => admin_url( 'wp-ajax.php' ),
                    'nonce'         => wp_create_nonce( 'nombrenonce' )
                ]
            );

        }

        public static function ejecutar() {

            // Gancho para crear el objeto
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ self:class, 'objeto_javascript' ] );

            // Gancho para usuarios logueados
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_mi_nombre_accion', 'receptor_ajax' );

            // Gancho para usuarios NO logueados
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mi_nombre_accion', 'receptor_ajax' );

        }

    }

// Se llama al método ejecutar para que quede activo el método AJAX a Recibir
Prefijo_Calculador_Ajax::ejecutar();
```

Agrega esto en tu archivo JavaScript donde usarás el método AJAX (jQuery)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    'use strict';

    var $btnCaldulador = $( '.boton-calculador' );

    $btnCaldulador.on( 'click', function(){

        var total = ''; // Valor obtenida de la función calduladora

        $.ajax({
            url         : nombreobjeto.adminUrl,
            method      : 'POST',
            dataType    : 'json',
            data        : {
                action      : 'mi_nombre_accion', // Nombre de la acción para que seleccione el gancho correcto // wp_ajax_mi_nombre_accion
                nonce       : nombreobjeto.nonce, // Seguridad nonce
                nuevoPrecio : total // Enviando el valor del nuevoPrecio
            }, success: function( data ) {
                console.log( data );


                if( data.resultado ) {

                    // ...

                } else {

                    // ...

                }

            }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Añado la respuesta del OP en modo Wiki de Comunidad, pues [la incluyó en su pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164040/revisions).</sub>

Al final he conseguido arreglar mi problema.  He enviado los datos mediante **AJAX**, pues, no me quedaba otra.

Básicamente, en la parte de JS y tras calcular el precio final, llamaba a una función a la cual le pasaba como parámetro el precio total.   La función es la siguiente:

```
function enviarPrecio(precio){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // Método de envio
    url:'url', // URL a la cual le enviamos los datos
    data: {precioFinal:precio}, // Datos que vamos a enviar, en este caso una variable llamada precioFinal con el precio
    beforeSend: function () { // Esto se ejecuta antes de enviar
            console.log("Procesando, espere por favor..."); 
    }
});
```

}

En cuanto al **functions.php**, tengo puesto lo siguiente:

```
if (isset($_POST['precioFinal'])) { // Si me llega por el POST algo con el nombre de precioFinal...

    // Acciones a llevar a cabo
}
```

Darle las gracias a @Gilbert Rodríguez, por su respuesta y ayuda.